# Gitlab-CI: Access nginx service in script section

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I access the nginx service in the script section of a Gitlab-CI job?

```
run_tests:
  image: curlimages/curl
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: bitnami/nginx
  script: 
    - curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

At the moment I always get the error:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 after 4 ms: Connection refused`

According to the bitnami nginx documentation, the container should display the standard page on port 8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case correct service hostname would be `bitnami-nginx` and yaml

```yaml
run_tests:
  image: curlimages/curl
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: bitnami/nginx
  script: 
    - curl http://bitnami-nginx:8080
```

As per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services

The default aliases for the service’s hostname are created from its image name following these rules:

- Everything after the colon (:) is stripped.
- Slash (/) is replaced with double underscores (__) and the primary alias is created.
- Slash (/) is replaced with a single dash (-) and the secondary alias is created (requires GitLab Runner v1.1.0 or higher).